# WinForms DateTimePicker Dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, popup, datetimepicker

I need to have a pop-up dialog like the Color Dialog or Save Dialog but for choosing a date from a calendar.  The DateTimePicker is what I need, but I don't know how to launch this like a pop-up dialog in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a DateTimePicker to a form and show the form as a dialog:

```
var picker = new DateTimePicker();
Form f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(picker);

var result = f.ShowDialog();
if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //get selected date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimePicker` is a `Control`, not a `Form`. You'll have to create your own `Form` and add the control to it; there is not a standard dialog for selecting dates.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but is there any way to make a dialog?

Comment: There is no way in win forms other than Form

Comment: @James: Like I said, you'll just need to create another `Form`, add the control (and any properties you'll need; I'd assume you'd need one to get/set the value displayed), then instantiate it and call `ShowDialog`. You'll probably also want to set the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog`.